# What is the internal structure of an Interface Builder .xib file?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, interface-builder

What is the internal structure of a .xib file used by [Interface Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder)?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://speirs.org/blog/2007/12/5/what-are-xib-files.html) blog entry.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Well a xib file is an **XML** file used by Interface Builder.

The header usually contains something similar to this:

```
<archive type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="7.10">
```

Then they consist of 'object' entries which represent objects contained within the nib.

```
<object class="NSMutableDictionary" key="IBDocument.PluginVersions">
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click a `xib` file > Open As > Source Code

You'll be able to see the entire `xib` file as code.